# how can i change color of separated div based on focus on nested input using CSS?

Tags: html, css

The structure is similar to this:

```
<div>
    <div id="selected">
        <div id="inBetweenDiv">
            <input id="action"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="changeThis"></div>
</div>
```

I want to change background of #changeThis on the focus of the input element.

Comment: Can you use javascript or jQuery? Because it's not possible using CSS only with the current markup.

Comment: @Mahatmasamatman:  it really is.

Comment: Oh I stand corrected, I would have never thought of writing it that way. Thanks for making me learn :)

Answer (score 5):

In pure CSS you could use the [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) pseudoclass

```css
#selected:focus-within ~ #changeThis {
   background: yellowgreen
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="selected">
        <div id="inBetweenDiv">
            <input id="action" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="changeThis">Change this</div>
</div>
```

---

Otherwise you could do the same via JS, if you need to support older browsers e.g.

```
var input = document.getElementById('action');
var ct    = document.getElementById('changeThis');

input.addEventListener('focus', () => { ct.classList.add('focus'); });
input.addEventListener('blur',  () => { ct.classList.remove('focus'); });
```

and in CSS – assuming that `#changeThis` has a default background already applied – you need to use a more specific selector like

```
#changeThis.focus {
   background: yellowgreen;
}
```

Comment: While this code is absolutely correct, I'd suggest an alternative selector: `#selected:focus-within + #changeThis {...}` purely because the `:focus-within` pseudo-class will match any ancestor `<div>` elements of the `<input>` when it has focus. Which, in practice, may select additional elements. Albeit in this case an `id` selector is being used so it's not terribly relevant or concerning here.

Comment: yes, it's more scoped, agree. I used div but I was referring to the outer div which actually has no attributes

Comment: Yeah, I know, I saw that when I looked back at the code; my initial comment was more of a *nota bene* for the OP. :)